# Splunk: Split a time period into hourly intervals

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

```
index="dummy" url="https://www.dummy.com" status="200 OK"  
| stats count by id 
| where count > 10
```

If I apply this above query for 1 day, I would get, for example

```
id            count
ABC             50
XYZ             60
..
```

This would mean ABC hit `https://www.dummy.com` 50 times in 1 day, and XYZ called that 60 times.

Now I want to check this for 1 day but with every two hours interval

Suppose, ABC called that request 25 times at 12:00 AM, then 25 times at 3:AM,
and XYZ called all the 60 requests between 12 AM and 2 AM

I want the output to look like this (time format doesn't matter)

```
id            count    time
XYZ             60   12:00 AM
ABC             25   12:00 AM
ABC             25   2:00 AM
..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [bin](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Bin) to group events into time buckets.  You can use any span value, but for the 2 hours you mentioned, the updated query would be:

```
index="dummy" url="https://www.dummy.com" status="200 OK"  
| bin _time span=2h
| stats count by id, _time 
| where count > 10
```